# Better way to achieve looped output result

Tags: php, combinatorics

I have 4 variables - say A, B, C and D

Each variable can have 4 values - say 1, 2, 3 and 4

I need to generate all possible combinations of values

Example of Expected Output:

```
 A B C D
---------
 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 2
 1 1 1 3
 1 1 1 4
 1 1 2 1
 1 1 2 2
 1 1 2 3
 .
 .
 .
 4 4 4 1
 4 4 4 2
 4 4 4 3
 4 4 4 4
```

I have wrote following loop

```
for ($A = 1 ; $A < 5 ; $A++){
 for ($B = 1 ; $B < 5 ; $B++){
  for ($C = 1 ; $C < 5 ; $C++){
   for ($D = 1 ; $D < 5 ; $D++){
    echo $A.$B.$C.$D;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any faster or better way to achieve above result?

Comment: @I-M-JM i have the solution but i can only display the result and not put them into arrays, and is also not sorted. anyway i'll try to solve this, this seems challenging for me.

Comment: are `A B C D` values constant?

Comment: @Viscocent yes, values are constant

Comment: Keep it simple. I believe your code is about as efficient as it gets...

Answer (score 4):

### Review

Your answer is perfectly fine for this usage, I would keep that.  If you were that deep in loops generally it would be a sign that something was wrong, but for this task it is perfectly okay.

I would recommend using upper case only for constants.

### Over Optimisation

This is actually a lot simpler than the other answers are making it out to be.  The best answer in terms of performance (which is a silly thing to aim for) that I can think of is:

```
$end = pow(4, 4);

for($i = 0; $i < $end; ++$i)
{
    echo 1111 + base_convert($i, 10, 4), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Addition is quite a cheap operation for a processor to perform.  Comparing the benchmarks from Elias Van Ootegem's answer shows that the above code is significantly quicker.  This is due to the loop running only on the numbers that it needs to and not having to check a string.  It also does not introduce any pre-computed magic numbers.

```
OP Time taken:    0.00325608253479
Elias Time taken: 0.0021388530731201
Pauls Time taken: 0.0016560554504395
```

The code I used for the benchmark was:

```
// OP version
$start = microtime(true);
for ($a=1;$a<5;++$a)
    for ($b=1;$b<5;++$b)
        for ($c=1;$c<5;++$c)
            for ($d=1;$d<5;++$d)
                echo $a, $b, $c, $d, PHP_EOL;
                //comma's are more efficient then dots here
echo 'OP Time taken: ', microtime(true) - $start, PHP_EOL;

// Elias version
$start = microtime(true);
for($i=156;$i<625;++$i)
{
    $str = base_convert($i, 10, 5);
    if (strstr($str, '0') === false)
        echo $str, PHP_EOL;
}
echo 'Elias Time taken: ', microtime(true) - $start, PHP_EOL;

// Paul Version
$start = microtime(true);
$end = base_convert(3333, 4, 10) + 1;

for($i = 0; $i < $end; ++$i)
{
    echo 1111 + base_convert($i, 10, 4), PHP_EOL;
}
echo 'Pauls Time taken: ', microtime(true) - $start, PHP_EOL;
```

### Overkill

If you do want to generalise the output you could create a function such as the one below (This is complete overkill, but demonstrates that the solution does not come from magic numbers.):

```
/**
 * Count in a base that has been offset from zero.
 *
 * @param int $digits The number of digits to use.
 * @param int $offset The offset from zero that the base uses.
 * @param int $base   The base to count in.
 */
function countInAnOffsetBase($digits, $offset, $base)
{
    $end = pow($base, $digits);
    $offset = str_repeat($offset, $digits);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $end; ++$i)
    {
        echo $offset + base_convert($i, 10, $base), PHP_EOL;
    }
}

countInAnOffsetBase(4, 1, 4);
// Or try 3, 4, 5 to count from 444 to 888 using the digits 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

This is almost as quick as the version I proposed at the top of this post.

### Note

The function and method above assume that the number will not roll over the base (for base 10, the offset + base must be less than 10).  An even more general function would specify the output base:

```
/**
 * Count in a base that has been offset from zero.
 *
 * @param int $digits The number of digits to use.
 * @param int $offset The offset from zero that the base uses.
 * @param int $base   The base to count in.
 * @param int $base   The base to output the count in.
 */
function countInAnOffsetBase($digits, $offset, $base, $outputBase)
{
    if ($offset + $base > $outputBase)
    {
        throw new OverflowException(
            'offset and base cannot be greater than outputBase otherwise ' .
            'the value will overflow.');
    }

    $end = pow($base, $digits);
    $offset = intval(str_repeat($offset, $digits), $outputBase);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $end; ++$i)
    {
        echo base_convert(
            $offset + intval(base_convert($i, 10, $base), $outputBase),
            10,
            $outputBase),
            PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nips, base 4 + 1111... why didn't I think of that! +1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there sure is a faster, easier and just all-round better way of solving your problem. The actual problem is that you've not taken enough time to actually analyze the situation. A finite number of combinations of *any* data shouldn't require a brute-force 4 level loop approach. (well, 99.99% of times, it shouldn't).

Start off, by looking at the data, and see if you can't find a pattern. In this case the pattern is much the same as a combination lock, only instead of 0 through 9, the possible digits are 1 through 4. It's, essentially a number system slap bang in the middle of binary and octal.

Try to think of the permutations as *bases*. Like a binary system has `100` to represent 4, you are working in base 5 (well, base 4, but we'll get to that):

```
0 0 0 1 //possibility 1
0 0 0 2 // possibility 2
0 0 0 3 // pos. 3
0 0 0 4 // pos. 4
0 0 1 0 // pos. 5
0 0 1 1 //pos 6
```

So, the first thing we need to know is, with 4 variables (or 4 positions, what is the total number of combinations? Simple: What is the highest number we can represent using base 5, if we only have 4 positions:

```
4 4 4 4 // == 4*(5^3) + 4*(5^2) + 4*(5^1) + 4*(5^0) == 624
```

Because the minimum value for each field is 1, we can also safely assume that the lowest value we can represent is:

```
1 1 1 1 // == 5^3 + 5^2 + 5^1 + 5^0 == 156
```

So all of the permutations will be within a given range: 156 - 624. That's as good a starting point as any:

```
$numbers = range(156, 624);
```

Now, to convert all of these numbers to base-5 strings, we can use [the function `base_convert`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php). After that, it's just a matter of looping over those numbers, and filtering out any strings that are either too short, or contain zeroes. I'll add the `range` bit, so you can see just how short the entire code will actually be:

```
$numbers = range(156, 624);
$strings = array();
foreach ($numbers as $num)
{
    $base = base_convert($num, 10, 5);
    //filter out the numbers that have 0's in them
    if (strstr($base, '0') === false)
        $strings[] = $base;
}
//example output:
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $strings);
```

The output is *exactly* what you are after.
In response to PeterVR's comment, I've put together a basic benchmark script, that merely echoes the numbers, doesn't construct an array and uses a `for` loop instead of a foreach, to better compare the speed differences (if any):

```
//Your version:
$start = microtime(true);
for ($a=1;$a<5;++$a)
    for ($b=1;$b<5;++$b)
        for ($c=1;$c<5;++$c)
            for ($d=1;$d<5;++$d)
                echo $a, $b, $c, $d, PHP_EOL;
                //comma's are more efficient then dots here
echo 'Time taken: ', microtime(true) - $start;
//my version
$start = microtime(true);
for($i=156;$i<625;++$i)
{
    $str = base_convert($i, 10, 5)
    if (strstr($str, '0') === false)
        echo $str, PHP_EOL;
}
echo 'Time taken: ', microtime(true) - $start;
```

I then ran each version a couple of times, using this command:

```
$ php v1.php > res1.txt
$ php v2.php > res2.txt
```

And compared the results using this command:

```
$ vimdiff res1.txt res2.txt
```

Which, as I said, showed that the only difference in output is the time both pieces of code take to run. The difference is minor, however, as I stated: my suggestion is marginally faster:

```
//your code
Time taken: 0.0016489028930664
//your code using concatenation, instead of comma's in echo statement:
Time taken: 0.0016589164733887
//my suggestion:
Time taken: 0.0016350746154785
```

So the conclusion, then, is simple:
My suggestion is faster, but the speed difference is negligible. The real benefit of *my* code is that, if the strings need to be 5 chars long, all you have to do is change the maximum from `624` to `3124` (== 44444 in base-5), your code requires a fifth(!) loop to be added.
Less code and less loops equals less chance for bugs, IMO. In short: my code is more flexible, that's why creating a reusable function is easy.

The code below is a function that build on my suggestion to tackle this problem using bases. It handles invalid input, ascending and descending values, and supports up to base 35 values of any length.

```
function generatePermutations($min, $max, $length)
{
    //avoid negative arguments
    $min = abs($min);
    $max = abs($max);
    $length = abs($length);
    if ($min > $max)
        array_reverse(generatePermutations($max, $min, $length));//reverse order
    if ($min > 35 || $max > 35)//validate arguments
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Max base is 35');
    $alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';//up to base 53
    if ($min > 9)
        $min = $alphabet{$min-10};//get char at offset $min-10, if $min is 10, that means char @0 == a
    $base = $max+1;//1 + 4
   if ($max > 9)
       $max = $alphabet{$max-10};
    $low = (int) base_convert(
        str_repeat((string) $min, $length),//make min string for base;
        $base,
        10
    );
    $high = (int) base_convert(
        str_repeat((string) $max, $length),
        $base,
        10
    );
    $strings = array();
    for ($low;$low<=$high;++$low)
        $strings[] = base_convert($low, 10, $base);
    return $strings;
}
generatePermutations(0, 15, 2);//generates list of valid colour strings
```

Now this function does not remove strings containing zeroes, because that is something that is required in *your* specific case. This function is more generic than that, so you'll have to loop over the array it returns, and remove those strings with a zero in there, if you are to use this code.
Other than that, this function should work just fine.

*Some theory*
I said that you could look at your strings as base-5 numbers. I also said that, actually, you're using base-4. Just to clear up any confusion that I may have caused: here's some background info on base-5/base-4 and the different approaches you can use to solve your problem:

We're used to our numbers being *decimal* (base 10), computers use a binary system. Every so often, we see other bases being used: colours in CSS files use the hexadecimal system (or base 16: 0 through F). Directory, and file access rights can be changed using octals (base 8: `sudo chmod 0777 -Rf /`, for example). But any base is possible, they all work the same way. The position determines the multiplier.
Positions are, like arrays, zero indexed. The index is the exponent of the base, and you multiply the value of that position with the base to the power of that position:

```
//a decimal:
123 == 1 * 10^2 + 2 * 10^1 + 3 * 10^0
```

The same combination is possible in base 4, too. To calculate the decimal value of this number (123) in base 4, simply replace `10`, by `4` in the sum I wrote above:

```
1 * 4^2 + 2 * 4^1 + 3 * 4^0
//or open your JS console and type:
1*Math.pow(4,2) + 2*Math.pow(4,1) + 3*Math.pow(4,0)
```

And you should find out that `123` in base 4 is the same as writing `27` in decimal.
Play around using all bases >= 4, to see what the same combination of digits yields in different bases.

Now, Why did I use base 5, when I said that actually, your numbers are base-4?
I'm using base 5, because the possible values for each position in a base-5 system is *0 - Base-1*, in this case 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 (5 possible values, hence base 5). But you don't want those combinations that use a 0, effectively removing one of the possible values for each given position, so you end up with base 4 (1, 2, 3, 4).
You could use base 4 here, too, but you'd have to increment each and every digit in the string, returned by `base_convert`, which is kind of sill IMO. I consider the `strstr` approach to be a lot easier.
Either way works fine, though:

```
//min base 4 is 0, max is: 3333 == 255:
$numbers = range(0, 255);
$strings = array();
foreach ($numbers as $num)
{
    //this is rubbish, use paul's suggestion instead!
    $strings[] = str_replace(
        array('0','1','2','3'),//change the digits base-4 uses
        array('1','2','3','4'),//to start at 1, instead of 0
        base_convert($num,10, 4)
    );
    //as Paul suggested, this is a lot better:
    $strings[] = 1111 + base_convert($num, 10, 4);
}
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $strings);
```

Comment: You actually call this less complicated? Not only is your code completely not understandable without the rest of your answer, my benchmark shows it is more then 3x slower then OP code (0.58 vs 0.18 for 500 cycles). It may look smart, but I am not impressed...

Comment: @PeterVR: Yes, I call this less complicated, if you know how to work with base-N. You say it's 3 times slower, but then I'd have to see how you benchmarked the code. I've done some benchmarking of my own, and added that to my answer. You can only get a meaningful benchmark comparison of 2 pieces of code, if both pieces of code do _exactly_ the same thing. my tests show that my code _always_ outperforms the OP's version. the difference is negligible, though, and I've expanded a bit on what the real benefit of my code is.

Comment: One little word for you: KISS

Comment: Dots are quicker than comma's according to my benchmarking.

Comment: @Paul: That's odd. PHP version? How did you benchmark the difference? Because, from the way the Zend Engine works, it's neigh on impossible for concatenation to be faster. I've posted a (simplified) explanation of why that is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596098/php-closing-tag-deletes-the-line-feed/20596645#20596645), and the comments contain a link with some more metrics.

Comment: @matheussilvapb: I'm with you, but it all depends on what you consider to be simpler

Comment: Yes, it is strange, I'm using PHP 5.5.12.  It seems that it is having a big impact on my benchmark results too. Here are some benchmarks: [Dots](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LQkv3L), [Commas](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AyTLQq).

Comment: @Paul: weird. Changing the version to 5.4.9 has the opposite effect (0.05 for dots vs 0.02 for comma's), but using 5.5-dev, after a couple of runs, comma's sometimes outperform dots, too :-S. Not sure what is happening behind the scenes. I'll have to dig through the source if I find the time...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem for me, simpler is more understandable and more readable. I don't know if it's the same for you but I feel like simpler code is better to other people analyze it.

Comment: @matheussilvapb: Yes, same here... but look at paul's suggested code. He basically took a similar approach to mine (using base 4), but in a more elegant way. The code is simple, and short. Short enough to write it as a one-liner: `for($i = 0, $end = pow(4,4); $i < $end; ++$i) echo 1111 + base_convert($i, 10, 4), PHP_EOL;` if that isn't simple, then I don't know what is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see any room for improvement in the OP's code. It is about as simple as it gets. Let me, as an example, compare the code of the OP with the answer from @EliasVanPeetegem

Let me start by sharing my full benchmark code:

```
echo 'test 1 = @Elias<br>';
$timer1 = microtime(true);
for ($t1 = 0; $t1 < 100; $t1++) {
    $numbers = range(156, 624);
    $strings = array();
    foreach ($numbers as $num)
    {
        $base = base_convert($num, 10, 5);
        //filter out the numbers that have 0's in them
        if (strstr($base, '0') === false)
            $strings[] = $base;
    }
}
echo microtime(true) - $timer1;

echo '<br>';

echo 'test 2 = OP<br>';
$timer2 = microtime(true);
for ($t2 = 0; $t2 < 100; $t2++) {
    $strings2 = array();
    for ($A = 1; $A < 5; $A++) {
        for ($B = 1; $B < 5; $B++) {
            for ($C = 1; $C < 5; $C++) {
                for ($D = 1; $D < 5; $D++) {
                    $strings2[] =  $A . $B . $C . $D;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo microtime(true) - $timer2;
```

which results in:

```
test 1 = @Elias
0.109359025955
test 2 = OP
0.0358469486237
```

I am not a pro in performance or benchmarking or anything of that sorts, but I really can not see any flaws in this test code. I don't see how these result can be so different from the ones @Elias got. I know I don't print the combinations, but both codes achieve the exact same outpu and are ran 100 times for a more reliable result. Please, anyone, let me know if there are any flaws in this code, I am very interested and willing to learn.

Now, why can't @Elias code be faster then the OP (imo).

- What the OP does is the following

  - 4^4 (= 256) basic iterations, where only the loop counter of each loop is used, and concatenated in the inner loop. A for loop is about as simple as it gets I believe, and I don't see how you can output 256 results without going trough 256 iterations. That is why I stick to my claim, *keep it simple, this is probably about as good as it gets*, until proven wrong (please do!)
- What @Elias does is the following:

  - you create an array with a sequence of 624 - 168 integers.( Basically that is a for loop with 468 iterations and $array[] = $i++; It is probably a bit better optimized in opcode, but I don't see this being possible without some sort of loop, so 468 'super'-iterations let's say.)
  - you go over each integer (468 iterations again),
  - call a function on the integer (468 function calls)
  - check the result for zeros with another function (468 comparisons and 468 functions)
  - and then store or output or whatever

So I really don't see how **468 assignments**, **936 function calls** and **468 comparisons** can possibly be more efficient or even faster then **256 concatenations**.

Please do explain if I am seeing this completely wrong. Again, I am no expert of any sorts, just a simple web developer that writes PHP for a living. I am very eager to learn!

Comment: What PHP version did you use? And perhaps consider changing the `range` + `foreach` to a simple `for` loop, as I've done. `range` constructs an array (which is a hashtable internally), on which `foreach` performs lookups + assignments. Also be aware that the nested loops in the OP's code all perform assignments, too: the inner loop performs `$D = $D + 1;` (which is what `$D++` does) 4^4 +1 times, same goes for every loop level (`$A` loop performs increment 4^1 + 1 times, next loop 4^2 + 1 times and so on). I can only say: my code ran marginally faster than the OP's version.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for both cases (permutations with and without repetition)

**first without repetition:**

You could use this as a general function to obtain permutations of an array:

```
function permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
$result=array();
    if (empty($items)) { 
        $result[]=$perms;
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            $result=array_merge($result, permute($newitems, $newperms));
         }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Second with repetition**

```
function permuteWithRep($input){
$countall=pow(count($input),count($input));
$result=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($input);$i++){
$currStep=pow(count($input),count($input)-($i+1));
$current=array();
for($j=0;$j<$countall;$j+=$currStep){
$current+=array_fill($j,$currStep,$input[($j/$currStep)%count($input)]);
}
$result[]=$current;
}
$r=transpose($result);
return $r;
}

    function transpose($array) {
        array_unshift($array, null);
        return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
    }
```

This will return an array of arrays with possible permutations,
to print values in the way you asked you may use this:

```
function print_array($arr){
echo implode(', ',$arr);
echo '<br/>';
}
```

Having all these together here is a test:

```
$input=array(1,2,3,4);
$x=permute($input);
$y=permuteWithRep($input);
echo'Without Repetitions:<br><br>';
array_map('print_array',$x);
echo'With Repetitions:<br><br>';
array_map('print_array',$y);
```

For any question please comment

Comment: Why do we feel the need to over-complicate something as simple as this?